# How do I fix this so that the ordered list is put into the textbox?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, try-catch

So basically the code should get the file path for the text file, then sort the values inside the text file. The values are entered as 'AAA;04:32,' this being the 3 character username, and time in minutes and seconds. And it should sort by time and just have the username in front still. This should then be put into the textbox.

```
string strExeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string strWorkPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strExeFilePath);
            #region
            try
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(strWorkPath, "LeaderboardEasy.txt");
                string readText = "File Not Found";

                var sorted = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                    .OrderBy(line => Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[':']))
                    .ThenBy(line => Int32.Parse(line.Split(':')[1]))
                    .ToList();
                
                easyLeaderboard.Text = sorted;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem reading the file: " + ex.Message);
            }
            #endregion
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with a clear description of the specific issue you are facing. Not too sure of what the issue is :).

Comment: `line.Split(';')[':']` looks *very strange*. Do you mean `line.Split(';')[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

If the time format ensures *leading zeroes*, you can sort lexicographically:

```
   var sorted = File
     .ReadLines(filePath) // No "All", we don't want premature materialization
     .OrderBy(line => line.Split(';')[1]) // Lexicographical ordering
     .ToList();
            
   // You should join collection into a single string 
   easyLeaderboard.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted);
```

If leading zeros are not mandatory (i.e. `07:04`, `7:04`, `7:4` can appear) you can parse into `DateTime` and order by `DateTime`

```
   var sorted = File
     .ReadLines(filePath)
     .OrderBy(line => DateTime.ParseExact(
        line.Split(';')[1], "H:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) 
     .ToList();
            
   // You should join collection into a single string 
   easyLeaderboard.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted);
```